# How do I set a post process layer to my camera?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I downloaded and imported the unity post processing package version 3.0.3 from Window > Package Manager.

[image: post process package]

Then I added to the Camera the Post-processing Layer component but then when I select Layer there is no postprocessing in the list :

[image: no postprocessing layer]

What I'm trying to archive is a drone grayscale black and white camera effect and later to make specific objects like enemies to be kind of light colors just like a uav effect view.

This is example image of what I want to archive as the effect in the camera:

[image: camera effect]

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@3.0/manual/Quick-start.html

You have to create a custom layer just like you use for any other thing. Rest is up to **PostProcessingVolume**. you assign this "**postprocessing**" **layer** to the game object where **PostProcessingVolume** **component** is attached to.

Answer (score 0):

The layer your camera is on needs to be set on the post-processing layer component.